# How can I write common methods in controller to perform CRUD operation on different table?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am working on one MVC project. In which I have many tables like `Location`,`Department`,`Skills`,`Stream`,`CurrentRole`etc.

I want to perform CRUD operations on those tables.

What I have done is I have written some methods to perform operations on `Location` table. There are 4 methods which are as follows.

Add Location :

```
public ActionResult AddLocation(tblCurrentLocation location)
        {
            //Logic to add location to the database.
        }
```

Edit Location :

```
   public ActionResult EditLocation(string id)
        {
            //Logic to display Edit form...
        }
```

Save edited data :

```
  [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SaveLocation(tblCurrentLocation tblCurrentLocation)
        {
            //Logic to update the data in database.
//This is POST method which will get called when user clicks 
//save after editing the data.
        }
```

and this is to delete the entry from database

```
 public ActionResult DeleteLocation(int id)
        {
            //Logic to delete row from database.
        }
```

If I follow this approach and write down methods for all(approx. 16) tables it will be like 50+ methods in my controller which is hard to maintain.

What I'm looking for is I would write common CRUD methods which will be able to accept data for all my tables and perform operations.

Is writing **generic methods** a solution? If yes, then how can I achieve it?

Is there any alternate method to achieve this?

Please help..

Thank you :)

Comment: Generic methods would be my first option, but in conjunction with a generic repository. There are plenty of examples for the later on here. You could start there.

Comment: @AndreiV Can you help with some example?
or link...
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are preforming basic CRUD operations I would suggest looking at the [Repository pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx).
An example of a Generic interface using the Repository pattern:

**IRepository**

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : IEntity
{
    IEnumerable<T> List { get; }
    void Add(T entity);
    void Delete(T entity);
    void Update(T entity);
    T FindById(int id);
}
```

**IEntity**

```
public class IEntity
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
}
```

**Example Implementation**

```
public class MyRepo : IRepository<MyClass> // MyClass needs to implement IEntity
{
    private readonly DBContext _context;

    public MyRepo(DBContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public List<MyClass> List()
    {
        return _context.Table.ToList();
    }

    // Other implementations of the IRepository interface
}
```

Note this in my example I am using Entity Framework

Here is a useful guide to implementation the Repository pattern with Entity Framework: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/688929/Repository-Pattern-and-Unit-of

Comment: Hey @jamie rees Thanks for your answer...
I'll check if this works first thing in the morning

Comment: Thats great news. Glad to help.